# Ruby on Rails deployment with Tailwind on AWS ElasticBeanstalk failing due to Node.js

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tailwind-css

I was wondering if anyone has experience of deploying A Rails 6 app with Tailwind to AWS.

I have tried a dozen times now however the build keeps failing.

I am getting the following error in code pipeline:

> Action execution failed
> Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ef9ce5572262bb0d'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-0ef9ce5572262bb0d] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...cy: nodejs for package: yarn-1.22.15-1.noarch --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: yarn-1.22.15-1.noarch (yarn) Requires: nodejs You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest. command 01_install_yarn in .ebextensions/01_rails_deploy.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

The start of file 01_rails_deploy.config in my .ebextensions directory looks like this:

```
commands:
  00_remove_old_node_if_present:
    command: "/bin/rm -rf /var/cache/yum && /usr/bin/yum remove -y nodejs && /bin/rm /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource* && /usr/bin/yum clean all"
    ignoreErrors: true
  01_install_yarn:
    command: "sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo && curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum install yarn -y"
  02_install_nodejs:
    command: "yum -y install nodejs"
  03_mkdir_webapp_dir:
    command: "mkdir /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  04_chown_webapp_dir:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  05_chmod_webapp_dir:
    command: "chmod 0744 /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Any help solving this issue would be really appriciated.

Thanks[image]

Comment: I just met the similar issue recently, it seems the problem is resulting from `curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -`. Some certificate issue happens here, it may be temporary. My solution is get rid of this line, and install the version that come with the base image.

Comment: Hi @sam 
Would you have the line you used?
Thanks,

Comment: I just delete this problematic line. and install nodejs directly. In my image, node v10 is installed.

Comment: Hi Sam, 

If you install in directly then when you autoscale the new instance will be missing it. Is that correct?

Comment: Not really. I mean I just use `apt install nodejs` in dockerfile, and whatever the version comes with the image will be installed. I don't have to using this line `curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -` to install nodejs 12 which is problematic now.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I understand now. Unfortunately we are not using Docker and are using the .ebextensions directory which is where our problems are coming from.